# how to use Mono List to deal with a input

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor

i have a input value，need to pass a Mono chain deal with it。the next input is dependence of the previous result。

```java
public class MonoMapReplaceTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String originStr = "hello";
        List<String> rules = List.of("+1", "+2", "+3");

        List<Mono<String>> monos = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String rule : rules) {
            Mono<String> valueFromRemote = getValueFromRemote(rule, originStr);
            monos.add(valueFromRemote);
        }
    }

    private static Mono<String> getValueFromRemote(String input,String originStr) {
        return Mono.just(input + originStr);
    }
}
```

expect result :+1+2+3hello

Answer (score 0):

For these purposes, do not use List<Mono>, because you will need to subscribe to each mono, and you need to subscribe to it once. Better Use Flux or Mono if needed i.e Mono as below example:

```
String originStr = "hello";
List<String> rules = List.of("+1", "+2", "+3");
return Mono.just(rules)
                .map(r -> {
                    String join = String.join("", r);
                    return join + originStr;
                });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).